# How do I reference a dynamically-created text field (within a Formik)?

Tags: reactjs, forms, dynamic, formik, formik-material-ui

I have a Formik form, including an initial value called `descriptions` (initialised as an empty array), in which I would like to store possible text field results.

The text fields only need to be created on an ad hoc basis, by changing the value of a matching checkbox: The user checks the box for "X Data", and as well as checking the box, an associated field is rendered. I have this part working.

The issue I have is that the newly rendered input isn't named! I'm assuming I need to name it something like `descriptions[x_data]`. Is this correct? How do I get this to work? Here's the pared-down version of the code I have working so far.

```
const sectionList = [
  {name: "x_data", label: "X Data"}, 
  {name: "y_data", label: "Y Data"}, 
]

...

<div>
  {sectionList.map(({ name, label }, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <Field component={MyCheckbox} name="sectionChoices" value={label} label={label} />
        {values.sectionChoices.indexOf(label) > -1 && (
          <Field
            component={TextField}
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
            name={`descriptions[${name}]`}.  // doesn't seem to work :-(
            label={'Description of ' + label}
          />
        )}
     </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: what's not working? If you do `descriptions[x_data]` Formik is going to look for `values.descriptions.x_data`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I examine the source, there’s no ‘name=‘ property. :-(

Comment: but there is desired input with correct label?

Comment: Yep, that's the confusing bit!

Comment: In my case i used like this. name={`descriptions[${index}].name`}

Comment: I'll look at that